# What is the probability that the most successful out of these twenty will be right at least 9 times out of the next 10 predictions they make?

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have twenty economists, each of whom makes their predictions based 
on the toss of a fair coin. What is the probability that the most successful out of these twenty will be right 
at least 9 times out of the next 10 predictions they make? (Here, the “most successful” economist is the one 
who makes the highest number of correct predictions out of all twenty economists.)

I don't understand where to start on this problem, please help?

How do I determine who the "most successful" economist is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ingredients:** The probability that at least one of the economists will be right at least $9$ times is $1$ minus  the probability that they all get $8$ or fewer right.

Let $p$ be the probability that a given economist gets $8$ or fewer right. Then the probability that they all get $8$ or fewer is $p^{20}$.

To find $p$, it is easiest to find $1-p$, the probability a given economist gets $9$ or more right.

We leave the cooking to you.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Alright, I'm stuck on the next and final question of my homework. And I like that you help without spoon feeding the answer. The next question wants to know what is the probability that the second most successful of the twenty economists will be right at least 9 times out of the next 10 predictions they make?

Comment: Same basic idea. We are interested in the probability that at least $2$ economists will be this lucky.

Comment: Right... Sadly, that doesn't help me much... How do you account for at least two of the economists being right at least 9 of the 10 times? I understand the probability of at least one of them getting it right, but two?

Comment: Travel through the complement, the probability that $0$ or $1$ are this lucky. The case $0$ has already been computed. For the case exactly $1$, the lucky economist can be chosen in $20$ ways. The probability she gets $9$ or more and the others don't is not hard to compute. Multiply by $20$. (If you are familiar with it, I am using the $1$ success case of a Binomial distribution.)

Answer (score 0):

For each economist, the probability to be right at least $9$ times out of $10$ predictions is 
$$10\times 0.5^9 \times 0.5^1 + 0.5^{10} = 11/1024$$
So the probability that all $20$ economists fail to be right at least $9$ times out of the next $10$ predictions is $(1-11/1024)^{20} = 0.8057304$

So the answer is $1-0.8057304 = 0.1942696$

Answer (score 0):

$$
Neconomists=20
$$
$$
Pdecision=0.5
$$

The probability for a single economist to attain an average accuracy of $0.9$ given a set of $10$ elements. 
$$
P1economist=(Pdecision)^9=(0.5)^9 \approx 0.001953125
$$
$$
P20economist=P1economist*20 \approx [0.0390625]
$$

Hopefully I have the right idea, but I am not quite confident in this conclusion.

Sincerely,

--

Jordan D. Ulmer